# Batch variables evaluation

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I'm writing a short batch script which is setting the needed time format.
I'm trying to evaluate the last dt variable so it will print the time when the variable was called unfortunately it's not working 
Here is a snippet for the script:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set  dt=%%a
set  YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set  MM=%dt:~4,2%
set  DD=%dt:~6,2%
set  HH=%dt:~8,2%
set  Min=%dt:~10,2%
set  Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set datestamp=%DD%-%MM%-%YYYY%
set timestamp=%HH%:%Min%:%Sec%
set fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause

echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
pause
```

Here is the ouput:

```
datestamp: "02-09-2015"
timestamp: "10:36:31"
fullstamp: "2015-09-02_10-36-31"
Press any key to continue . . .
timestamp: "10:36:31"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It's printing the same value in those two echo statements.
Is there anyway to fix it ?

Comment: See my answer.  The task you need to do will determine the best way to get the current time.

Answer (score 0):

The `Wmic` command gets the date and time at that moment.

All other lines use that same exact date and time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @foxidrive... you are using the same value in both cases. Assuming you want the current time when you display you can do something like this.

```
@echo off
call :GetDateTime
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause

call :GetDateTime
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
pause
goto :eof

:GetDateTime
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set datestamp=%DD%-%MM%-%YYYY%
set timestamp=%HH%:%Min%:%Sec%
set fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%
goto :eof
```